# Fast ellipsoid(s) intersection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geometry, complexity-theory, computational-geometry

Let's say I've got 1 million arbitrarily shaped, arbitrarily oriented N-dimensional ellipsoids scattered randomly through N-dimensional space.  Given a sub set of ellipsoids, I want to "quickly" determine the set of all ellipsoids that the ellipsoids from the first set intersects.

There's got to be an algorithm for this.  What is it?  What is it's "O" complexity?

Comment: Why? Without the why, this smells of "do my homework for me".

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that your ellipsoids are stored in some kind of tree-like data structure, such as the N-dimensional equivalent of a quad-tree?  If not, then this is pretty much an *O(MN)* problem, where *M* is the size of the subset, and *N* is the size of the set.

Comment: @spender - excellent! That means that the answer will be easy to come by.  The why is because I want to bound arbitrary probability distributions using families of spheres.  Determining which family of spheres overlap will allow me to make a first cut at solving a generalized likelihood problem. - no this is not a homework problem.

Comment: @Oli YES! let's assume that.  I was trying to rephrase the problem so that I could use a kd-tree, but I came up short.  Specifically, I was going to describe a 3D sphere as a point in 4D space: (x,y,z,radius).  But I immediately realized that you can't use the normal Euclidean distance metric.

Comment: Is the core of the problem the intersecting of the actual ellipsoids or an algorithm to divide your 1 million objects into a more sensible subset?

Comment: @Pedery - I want the ultimate goal to be as I described it in the post above - however, how best to arrive at that end goal, I'm not sure.  If it helps to solve two sub problems, then by all means we should do that.

Comment: This may work or not depending on your parameters. Use something like [**this**](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/cuboids.4171/) for a  fast calculation of the intersections of the convex hulls, and only if they intersect, calculate the ellipsoid intersection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "O" complexity suffers from the *curse of dimensionality* if you're allowing for N-dimensional data. (See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) for more about that). I recommend borrowing from physics simulation and dividing this problem into a "broad phase" and a narrow phase:

- The broad phase conservatively finds drastically smaller set of pairs of potentially overlapping ellipses.
- The narrow phase trims the set of potentially overlapping pairs of ellipses to those pairs that actually do overlap.

The narrow phase is a straightforward computational geometry problem of testing for intersection between arbitrary ellipses. For the broad phase you'll want to use a spatial structure such as a spatial hash, spatial tree (R-tree, Kd-tree, X-tree, UB-tree, etc...), or ad-hoc structure given some special properties of the data you're loading (such as an unbalanced tree or hash).

The current popular method is a Kd-tree. There's a lot of documentation and already coded versions of the Kd-tree that are readily configurable, so I recommend you look online. (Google is your friend on this one.) The advantage of using most tree structures is that if set you're looking for intersections with is relatively compact you can search through the tree only once and find the intersections without having to perform multiple tree traversals. This will help with cache (be it from main memory or disk) access patterns. The same algorithm can handle disparate membered queries. It's likely you're doing work that would benefit greatly from the compact query set properties, however.

A Kd-tree won't fix your problems for all ellipsoids -- for example, if you have an ellipsoid of dimension N whose primary axis is from (0, 0, 0, 0, ...) through  (1, 1, 1, 1, ...) but with small or inconsequential secondary axes (and henceforth doesn't intersect much) will still need to be an a node that covers [0,1] in all N dimensions. If your ellipsoids fall in [0,1]^n, then every ellipsoid will test for intersection with the aforementioned inconvenient ellipsoid. However, with real world data (and even most synthetic unless you're really trying hard to make Kd-trees slow) the Kd-tree approach should be a win.

If you expect Kd-tree to be a success for thousand-dimension ellipsoids, chances are you're better off with a brute force search. (The aforementioned curse of dimensionality.) However...

One million entries isn't too bad if you've got an optimized implementation, but if you're doing a lot of queries (millions) it's going to be slow (on the order of 10 seconds or worse). I've seen some amazing numbers come out of well-optimized vectorized code, however. (Even shipped some products using this strategy.) With the right cache coherency, brute-forcing would take only milliseconds at most. This means either ASM or vector intrinsics in C/C++ -- not sure which language you're working in.

For most data, O complexity (disregarding the curse of dimensionality) should be about amortized O(m log n) for queries (once the tree is built) where m is the number of ellipses in the query set and n is the number of ellipses in the data set. Building the data itself shouldn't be worse than O(n log n). Multiply everything by Exp(d) where d is dimension -- that's the way it goes with this sort of thing.

Comment: Fascinating! Thank you for the input.  So my take-away message is that, if I can make some assumptions about the maximum size of the ellipsoids, then I can use a Kd-tree to quickly cull the space down to a size that is more manageable for brute force computational geometry problem.

Comment: Essentially yes. And if you really need to because of space constraints, you can do it from disk since tree traversal is much less bandwidth dependent than brute force. But a well-optimized brute force solution (if it comes down to it because of requirements I don't know of here) can still work. I've actually shipped games that brute-force similar sorts of problems in a few milliseconds per frame, but that was a lot of careful optimization.

Comment: If you don't want to use a pre-rolled Kd-tree implementation and instead would rather use your own structure, if the ellipsoids are of fairly consistent size, a spatial hash structure is a lot easier to implement and can have some superior performance depending on the data itself. Kd-trees are generally more agnostic to data but have more complex operations slowing them down. Both are highly sensitive to dimensionality.